# PHP line break br with ENT_QUOTES

Tags: php, mysql, break

Is it possible to use ENT_QUOTES and still use any method to break the line?

```
  $title = htmlentities($_REQUEST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

When i input in the field for example:

```
<input type="text" value="Teacher: Don't cheat at the exam<br /> 1. Rule<br /> 2. Rule<br /> 3. Rule">
```

And it normally must look like this:

```
Teacher: Don't cheat at the exam
1. Rule
2. Rule
3. Rule
```

But i get this:

```
Teacher: Don't cheat at the exam<br /> 1. Rule<br /> 2. Rule<br /> 3. Rule
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: When I try your code the output is `Teacher: Don't cheat at the exam<br /> 1. Rule<br /> 2. Rule<br /> 3. Rule`.

Comment: Are you using `strip_tags()` in the real code?

Comment: There are no quotes in your input value, so `ENT_QUOTES` makes no difference. It still translates `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`.

Comment: Yes sadly I got the same. Im hoppeless :S I don't know what happend?

Comment: If you want the `<br/>` elements to be rendered as line breaks, you shouldn't use `htmlentities()`. The whole point of that function is to prevent any HTML tags from being processed.

Comment: Yes but when I use this character: ( ' ) and ( " ). Then I got problem's without ENT_QUOTES!

Comment: I can use `<br>` without ENT_QUOTES but then I get error's because the characters ( ' ) and ( " )??

Comment: You need to show the whole code. Whether you need to use `htmlentities` depends on how you're using the variable.

Comment: All I wanna do is get Linebreak's with `ENT_QUOTES`... Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting an error because of the quote characters. They don't have any special meaning in the text of HTML. The only time they need to be encoded is if you're using the variable to fill in an HTML attribute, like `echo "<input value='$title'>";`. But it should be OK if the `<br>` gets encoded there, they'll be decoded properly.

Comment: ok here is the code
`$title = htmlentities($_REQUEST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
$description = htmlentities($_REQUEST['description'], ENT_QUOTES);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO funn SET ac1='$ac1', ac2='po', ac3='po', imglink='$imglink', title='$title', description='$description', publisher='$name', published='$published'") or die("Your data cannot saved".mysql_error());`

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: You should be using `mysql_real_escape_string`, not `htmlentities`.

Comment: when you use this character ' its ok with ENT_QUOTES... But once i remove ENT_QUOTES I get sql injection... I would like to use ENT_QUOTES and breake the lines anyhow?

Comment: `htmlentities` is not for escaping database queries. That's what `mysql_real_escape_string` is for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109288/discussion-between-flamur-beqiraj-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

The very essence of `htmlentities()` is converting certain characters to HTML entities, and this includes `<` which becomes `&lt;` and `>` which becomes `&gt;`. The `ENT_QUOTES` is not relevant here.

So if you are using `htmlentities()` to filter your input (not sure you should, also you should probably specify `$_POST` etc.), you should output it with the opposite function if you want HTML to work:

Example:

```
$title = htmlentities($_POST['title']);
...
echo html_entity_decode($title); // outputs proper HTML
```

But devoid of more context, this example is meaningless and there is almost certainly a better way to do this in your project.

Comment: `$title = htmlentities($_REQUEST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
$description = htmlentities($_REQUEST['description'], ENT_QUOTES);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO funn SET ac1='$ac1', ac2='po', ac3='po', imglink='$imglink', title='$title', description='$description', publisher='$name', published='$published'") or die("Your data cannot saved".mysql_error());`

Comment: without ENT_QUOTES when you add this ' or this " than the  code get's sql injection... I would like to use ENT_QUOTES and anyhow use breaks?

Comment: You shouldn't use htmlentities() for MySQL input sanitizaton. The best method is to use prepared statements (I personally like PHP-MySQLiDB, a library that utilizes them and makes it easier to write certain queries). Failing that, use something like mysqli_real_escape_string().